# Desperate for help on low engine oil light 2010 Tiguan

Tags: oil, warning-light, oil-pressure

In August 2019, someone hit and totaled my 2005 Toyota Corolla. I purchased a used 2010 Tiguan. From day 0 it has had issues. I drove the car home but as I got off the highway it screamed and flashed low oil pressure. I pulled over to check the oil but everything appeared fine. The light disappeared instantly with no recurrence. Nearer my home it happened again.

I contacted the dealership immediately and they sent a tow truck the next day and brought the vehicle to their garage. To my knowledge (just what they told me) they replaced a sensor and could not replicate the issue. The issue immediately reoccurred for me once I had the vehicle again. I contacted them again and they asked me to bring it to my local VW dealership and they would pay for the inspection. The VW dealership found no codes despite the incident happening within the last 24 hours.

Now, as Winter approached, the issue seemed to fade and my regular commute is very short (10 minutes) so the issue was not at the forefront of my mind. Even with the issue occurring rarely during this time period the vehicle drove fine. Now that it is back to the warmer months and the quarantine is lifting I’m having to make some longer trips again and the screaming and flashing light is appearing more and more often. I will describe when I have seen it most often and when it does not occur:

A few baselines:

- The oil is full
- VW said the pressure was fine in their tests and
  again no codes
- I also checked for codes within an hour of warnings -
  0 codes found
- It never occurs at highway speeds
- It never appears within 20 minutes or so of driving if the car is cool
- I believe it is more likely to appear when my foot is off the accelerator not
  necessarily breaking
- Breaking seems to make it more likely to appear
- Taking sharper turns or going downhill make it more likely to appear
- It occurs more when hot

Currently it has 5w-30 in it which is in spec. I do not know if this is related because I do not know what was in it before it was last changed since I did not own it but it was still having issues then.

As an example, I drove to my parent's house a couple of days ago for my birthday and the vehicle was fine getting to the highway ~20 mins. Getting off one highway onto another on a 270deg ramp breaking it went off. No problems on that highway and then once off it went off very often at almost every slight slowdown. I pulled off into a parking lot to let it cool down for ~15 minutes to hopefully finish the rest of the way in peace. It went off once more after ~10 minutes more driving before I got where I was going.

It’s clear to me that whoever originally got rid of the vehicle must have had this issue. The carfax was immaculate. It was effectively a 1 owner car and they had taken it to the dealer for every 10k mile recommended maintenance. I would not have seen this during the test drive as I mentioned it takes some time and is more likely under certain conditions. I do not know what responsibility the dealer has to fix this issue. My understanding is the law is quite lax here and does not protect the buyer much if at all.

Pretty lousy situation for the first car I bought (the corolla was given to me. may she rest in peace.)

What should I do?

Comment: Check the engime wiring for chaffing - sounds like a damaged wire...

Comment: @SolarMike thanks for the reply. Anything in particular about what I describe make you think this?

Comment: This is an answer @DavidSupportsMonica, I'd write it myself but you already have.

Comment: @GdD Thanks for the encouragement. Suggestion taken.

Comment: No help, but I had a Audi that the oil light was always on and the dealer could not fix it . I just remembered to check the oil level regularly.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by “screamed”?

Comment: @HandyHowie I suppose I'm using that word for dramatic effect. I just mean that it is very load and very annoying just as a scream would be

Answer (score 1):

The items that suggest intermittent wire chafing to me are its occurrence intermittently, "when braking," and during "sharper turns or going downhill."

In each of these, the driveline and motor will move around on their mounts as the car goes from accelerate/steady state to braking's deceleration. Physical movement of stuff within the car body could easily cause a wire to move and intermittently make a connection.

I'd look specifically at the wire(s) to the oil sensor(s). I'm not familiar with the Tiguan motor. Oil sensors are typically located hear the motor's oil pump, which is usually low in the block, or screwed into the block where the sensor can "read" what's going on in an internal oil passage.

Comment: While this is great information, to make it better, you might display information as to where to look for the oil sensor(s) and wire(s). Not only could it help the OP, but whomever might come in behind them with the same type of question.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 You're absolutely right...and I have no experience whatsoever with a Tiguan. I can (and will) amend, but I can't offer much info.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica The fact that it is also temperature dependent seems to suggest it's not an issue like this correct? I have never had the issue occur below full engine temp and the frequency of occurrence increases tenfold between these warmer months (I'm in CT by the way) and the winter months

Comment: @CircArgs Not necessarily, IMO. A wire's insulation could remain relatively resistant to movement when cold. When warmed, it could get softer and allow movement and an electrical connection.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica okay I will take a look. This seems like a particularly trickier thing to spot. Seems like it could be subtle. It could even be within the connector housing no? Anything that could help me? I plan to switch the 30 weight oil to 40 weight to test that potentially simple solution. Looking above nothing seems out of place but as you say the wire I should be looking for is probably more obscure so I may have a better look while I'm underneath the car.

Comment: @CircArgs Not directly underneath. The oil pump pickup is at the bottom of the sump, but the oil pump itself is usually a bit higher, as it has to be driven (somehow) from the crankshaft. At the bottom of the sump you might find an oil temperature sensor, but not I think an oil pressure sensor.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Thanks for the quick replies. I found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ML_viMXuB0 which shows the oil pressure sensor. It looks like it's new. no obvious fraying or anything. Looks quite well protected. Sheathed in a ribbed plastic tube and is affixed to the sensor connector. The wire is not exposed

Comment: @CircArgs Remember the connectors, they're part of the circuit too. And the connection (usually crimped) between a wire and a connector piece could itself be faulty. If you can identify where that wire enters the computer, you could try bypassing the wire with a jumper, to take the possibly-problematic wire and its connections out of the circuit. Also consider changing the sensor.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica well I will let you continue...

Comment: @SolarMike Oh please weigh in here! I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @CircArgs, while the engine is on I would (very safely) move the wire that connects to that sensor and look to see if I can re-create that problem. Try moving the connector harness, the wires, press the wires together in case there's chafing, be thorough. If you get an oil warning light doing that I'd say you've found your culprit. You may need someone to sit in the car and watch for lights while you do that. If it is hard to reach you can tie some string to it.

Comment: @GdD This is an excellent suggestion.

Comment: @GdD I will give this a try. I intend to give the car a ride that would typically trigger the alert so the oil will be about as thin as ever, park and measure the idle and rev oil pressure. I swapped 30 weight oil with 40 weight. I will report back ~4-5 days with a summary as an edit in my post. Also, I realized I have 100k extended warranty but based on my experience with techs saying there's no codes for oil pressure and I've been told by others there wouldn't be a code I have degrading faith in techs

Comment: @CircArgs Do report back. Your comment mentions that the car has now thrown or saved any OBD error codes. That's really interesting, as the OBD system should retain a record of any codes set (even if the error later self-rectified), and one would certainly think that low engine oil pressure would trigger a code. I am far from expert in the OBD system, however, so can't do more than say this behavior too seems incorrect.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica I too thought a code would show up. Apparently this is not the case for oil pressure which is shocking to me. I was told it wasn't a fault of the ECU but rather the sensor "does not connect to the computer". As to whether this is true I only have my current experience to say it seems so